# Restrict Maximum Number of Characters in a Textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have created a textbox and can put an infinite number of characters in it, I want to restrict that to only allow the user to type in 250 characters as this is the limit in my database.

I have tried `myTextBox.MaxLength = 250`

this will still allow the user to type in more than 250 but when I go back in it will only display 250 which means that some data after this amount is lost and the user might not be aware.

I am looking for a way to restrict any more characters from being entered after 250 characters.

Comment: Is this Windows Forms or something else? What does "go back in" mean?

Comment: yes, I should have mentioned this.  it's a windows form application. I think what I a doing wrong is that I am setting the limit to the value assigned to the text box and not when loading the component.  I just tried that there and it worked for me.

Comment: Settings the `MaxLength` property doesn't allow to either enter or paste a higher number of chars. But it's not forbidden to set the Text property, in code, to a longer string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that I was limiting the size of the string being displayed on my form after I pull the data from the database when I used `myTextBox.MaxLength = 250` when loading my form. here I was actually limiting the amount of text being displayed and not the amount of text the user could add.

by adding the code `myTextBox.MaxLength = 250` when loading the component it now limits the amount of character I can type in the text box.

Comment: Why use code at all? Why not set the property in the designer? You should set everything in the designer that you can. You only need to use code if you won't know the value until run time.